# Boost.Python: expose class member which is a pointer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ class that would like to expose to Python. (Assuming this class has already been written and couldn't be easily modified). In this class, there is a member which is a pointer, and I would like to expose that member as well. Here is a minimal version of the code.

```
struct C {
  C(const char* _a) { a = new std::string(_a); }
  ~C() { delete a; }
  std::string *a;
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(text_detection)
{
  class_<C>("C", init<const char*>())
      .def_readonly("a", &C::a);
}
```

It compiles okay, except that there is a Python runtime error when I tried to access that field:

```
>>> c = C("hello")
>>> c.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*
```

which is understandable. But the question is that is it possible to expose member pointer `a` through Boost Python at all? And how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `def_readonly`, use `add_property` with a custom getter. You'll need to wrap the getter in [`make_function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/boost_python_make_function_hpp.html), and since the getter is returning a `const&` you must also specify a [`return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/models_of_callpolicies.html#function_invocation_and_creation.models_of_callpolicies.boost_python_return_value_policy.class_template_return_value_poli).

```
std::string const& get_a(C const& c)
{
  return *(c.a);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(text_detection)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<C>("C", init<const char*>())
    .add_property("a", make_function(get_a, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()))
    ;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b0bfda298a66b32)